# Ruby on Rails: how to set size of number_field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone show me how to set the size of `number_field` in rails? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<%= f.number_field :status, size: "10", ...
```

but this works:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, size: "10", ...
```

Thanks

Comment: check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag and http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag for options.. see which one helpful for you.

Comment: ...The other person deleted his answer ...but I found out size will change when we reduce the range of input using, e.g. in

Comment: @vv I deleted because it seems.. That answer is not what you are looking for.

Comment: It worked :)   ./////

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `:max` option.

```
<%= f.number_field :name, max: 10, .. %>
```

Read the documentation [`number_field_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag).

> `number_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})`
>
> Creates a number field.

**Options**

- `:min` - The minimum acceptable value.
- `:max` - The maximum acceptable value.
- `:in` - A range specifying the :min and :max values.
- `:step` - The acceptable value granularity.

Comment: Is that for the range of input values? Would that work on the size of the placeholder?

Comment: @vvofdcx I don't know the actual need of your. But I gave all possible option that you can use.

Comment: Could you show me how to set the size of number_field? e.g. 10px? Thanks

Comment: Lol just found out the size will change based on max&min. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form.number_field :n, {min: 0, max: 99} %>
```

This tag has not any syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `number_field_tag` and I had to add empty braces for second parameter when I was not using value.

```
number_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

This is what documentation says and I did not use value so my code with max looks like this

```
<%= number_field_tag :name,{}, max: @max_amount %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 (and Rails 5.2, and Chrome), I've found setting `max` doesn't work (for me).

However, it's simply possible to set the width by using the `style` attribute:

```
<%= number_field_tag :count, 20, style: "width:70px;" %>
```

(Or, as a possibly cleaner solution, give it a CSS class that sets this width.)